# UEFI/BIOS after Linux Mint 19.1 installation not booting up, showing boot menu instead

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

I am using a laptop Lenovo ThinkPad E570 ([link to manufacturer](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-e-series/Thinkpad-E570/p/22TP2TEE570)).

I installed Linux Mint 19.1 onto this laptop.

After installing when I reboot laptop I am getting this screen:

[image: boot menu]

---

If I press Enter on the Ubuntu at startup I am getting same screen again.

Question is how to boot directly to Mint?

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: @jsotola, how can I get rid of this situation ?

Comment: what is the situation? ... it appears to be a PC boot screen of some type ... perhaps your PC BIOS is not configured correctly

Comment: @jsotola, How to configure PC BIOS correctly. I am getting this after installation of Linux mint.

Answer (score 0):

Find out how to enter UEFI/BIOS on your laptop, you may use this [link to manufacturer](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-e-series/Thinkpad-E570/p/22TP2TEE570) to download a user's manual called *User Guide*, just right off the top of *Tech Specs*.

---

In your UEFI/BIOS go to Boot, change order to `ubuntu` and you should be done.

Comment: Your solution is not working. 

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3004019709666114&set=p.3004019709666114&type=3&theater

Comment: @Foysal Did you disable the Secure Boot by the way? Either way, please show us all your UEFI boot options whatever they are, thank you.

Comment: @Foysal If you press Enter on the Ubuntu at startup, does it even boot? You did not mention this.

Comment: How to disable Secure Boot ? If I press Enter on the Ubuntu at startup I am getting same screen again. Which are UEFI boot options ?  Is this https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRqlK.jpg  ?

Comment: @Foysal Try Security tab.

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not make up your mind if you want legacy BIOS (MBR) or UEFI/GPT, or both, and whether you want to install and boot another distro in the future.

The idea is to tell your BIOS to directly boot into the boot loader, which would be called `grub`. Your BIOS settings have to be correct when you install.

In my BIOS ("Visual"/intel) I have two checkboxes: "Legacy" and/or "UEFI". Plus there are the options to boot via network or CD or USB. Plus Uefi Shell.

Comment: What should I do now ?

Comment: [How To - Change Boot Order in BIOS - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ru1zIGWzED8)

Comment: The screenshot is informative - but I don't even know if that "ubuntu" entry works, and why it is not called "mint" or "grub".  This is like saying "My car won't start" and then you show a picture of a closed garage door. Is it locked? You want a remote? It has batteries? You want no garage door? ...you do know about the **F2 key** after power-on, to enter BIOS?

Comment: @rastafile Mint (apart from Debian edition) is based on Ubuntu and in boot order it usually shows as `ubuntu`.

Comment: Thanks @rastafile. Actually I am in Dark. I don't know which one is Car and which one is Garage.